# Should fastlane created .cer and .mobileprovision files be stored in git?

Tags: xcode, git, fastlane, fastlane-match

I'm using `fastlane` to deploy my iOS app and have just started using `match` as well. After deploying, in the root of my project directory are `.cer` and `.mobileprovision` files.

Should these be committed to the project git repository? Or will they be created on each machine I build on?

Update: I think my beta lane definition is wrong, although I've deployed 2 builds using it.  It looks like this:

```
lane :beta do
    # match(type: "appstore")
    get_certificates  
    get_provisioning_profile

    gym(scheme: "MyApp Release")
    pilot
    changelog_from_git_commits
 end
```

Would using the match and removing `get_certificates` and `get_provisioning_profile` affect what's happening?

Comment: Can you share your `Fastfile` and what commands exactly you are executing in which order?

Comment: @janpio - I updated the question with the beta lane of the `Fastfile`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to check them in. You should uncomment the match command and add `readonly: true` as a parameter so it can be loaded when the files are missing or outdated. `match(type: "appstore", readonly: true)`